# Using OpenApi Generator, is it possible to generate kotlin clients, which contain only the endpoints tagged by specific tags?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

Given this spec:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/notes": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "drinks"
        ],
        "summary": "get all notes",
        "operationId": "notesEndpoint",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SimpleNoteDto"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "notDrinks"
        ],
        "summary": "add new note",
        "operationId": "insertNoteEndpoint",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SimpleNoteDto"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SimpleNoteDto"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "SimpleNoteDto": {
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "name": {
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 0,
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to generate clients that contain only a specified tag? For example if using tag = "drinks", I could get only this part of the API:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/notes": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "drinks"
        ],
        "summary": "get all notes",
        "operationId": "notesEndpoint",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SimpleNoteDto"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "SimpleNoteDto": {
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "name": {
            "maxLength": 50,
            "minLength": 0,
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am seeking a solution that uses the gradle open api plugin. An alternative way that would help me is a way to split the specification file based on the `tags` field. It should also filter out the model/schema definitions which are not used. I want to have a multimodule project, where each part of the Api specified by tags would get generated into a separate place, in order to reduce the amount of recompilations.

I have tried to use the "apiFilesConstrainedTo" config field but it doesn't seem to be working with tags, but with exact file names.

Thanks for reading.